# Is there any api which give suggestion words?

Tags: iphone, android

I want to ask is there any api which return list of suggestions of words on giving input in any text control in any platform.

For example when we type in EditText in android through soft keyboard , keyboard  returns some suggestions so my question is that is there  any api which gives the suggestions of corresponding input words(Platform does not matter).

I am clearing it by a example suppose i type ab in EditText then the keyboard gives suggestions like Ab abc anita ashima  etc.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For android you can try:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: @Harry your answer is right you may post it as an answer below [=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the answer , there is a api for giving related word suggestions and the link for this is  http://docs.wordnik.com/api/methods#relateds